# Index issue with digitising OS MasterMapdata from OS Data Hub in QGIS

Tags: qgis, digitizing, ordnance-survey, indexing

Using QGIS 3.18.3 (Zurich). From the OS Data Hub (https://osdatahub.os.uk/) I've brought in the OS MasterMap "Topographic Line" data, via WFS/OGC API - Features option, and this has loaded fine. Response time for panning and zooming is very quick. However, I've now created an empty .shp to digitize elements of OSMM into. When I click the Pen icon to start digitizing, everything seems to stop, well, a progress bar is working away at the bottom of the screen calculating something!

I presume QGIS is creating an index of some sort here for the session to allow the digitizing process to be much quicker. However, I also presume that the index needs to work through the whole of the OSMM Britain data that I'm accessing, so this process would take a very long time!

Is there any way you can speed this indexing process up, or restrict the geographic area of the session index created?

For general day-to-day use, I would probably only need to index a large rectangle of OSMM around Warwickshire County.

Are there any settings I need to make sure are set for this?

Comment: I wouldn't expect an issue (or a reload of the WFS data) when you open a new file to digtise. But you could save the features of interest (Warwickshire) as a geopackage before you try to digitise. Also beware of derived copyright issues if you trace from OS data

Comment: If you do 'Export' > 'Save Selected Features As...' from a WFS layer then make sure you tick the check-box for 'Extent' and click 'Map Canvas Extent'. This can really speed up the time it takes to export.

Comment: I've been working with a chap from the OS to look at (and hopefully resolve) this issue. Today, we found that when you turn 'Snapping" off in QGIS you do not get the problem, and can then create/edit data normally over the WFS OSMM Topogographic data. When snapping is turned on, the software locks up again (the dreaded spinning icon on the screen.) I wonder what QGIS is doing at this point? Is it building an index of  the whole of the OSMM data (covers Great Britain) so it can perform snapping digitising?